# Print key value pairs in specific format

Tags: python, dictionary

We're doing some basic python exercises in order to get familiar with syntax, and I'm having issues with two of them which require us to print the key value pairs in a specific way. Both of them require us to populate a dictionary using a for loop, which I can do fine, but they also require us to print out the entire dictionary in a way that I've been unable to replicate.

The desired format of printing goes like so {512: 8, 729: 9, 1000: 10}, whereas the closest I've gotten to replicating it is [(512, 8), (729, 9), (1000, 10)]

This is my code, it's supposed to populate the dictionary using numbers from m to n as the value, and their cube as the key

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = int(input())
    n = int(input())
    x = int(input())
    d={}
    for i in range(m ,n+1):
        d[i**3]=(i)
    if x>=m and x<=n:
        print(d[x])
    else:
        print("no data")
    print(sorted(d.items()))
```

I know my dictionary is basically sorted from the start, I'm only using sorted because it looks closer to what I need in comparison to just using print(d.items()).

Any advice is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `print(repr(d))`

Comment: @Ruzihm, thank you, that works perfectly

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but is there a reason that simply `print(d)` doesn't work (given that `print(repr(d))` seemingly does)?

Comment: oh yep, that's true. silly me.

Comment: You can use comprehension to generate the dictionary: ```d = {_**3:_ for _ in range(m, n+1)})``` and then just ```print(d)``` or, even better, skip initializing ```d``` and just ```print()``` the comprehension directly.

Comment: Better not to use `_` for a variable name if you're going to use its value for anything. `_**3` looks strange, and it's conventional to use `_` to indicate when a value will *not* be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to even use `repr` for this: simply `print(d)` itself. The `print` function will convert the dictionary to a string automatically, in exactly the format you require.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str(dict)` to convert a dictionary `d` to a string with that format, so you can use `print(str(d))` or even more simply, `print(d)` to print it:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = int(input())
    n = int(input())
    x = int(input())
    d={}
    for i in range(m ,n+1):
        d[i**3]=(i)
    if x>=m and x<=n:
        print(d[x])
    else:
        print("no data")
    print(d)
```